# The direction of the magnetic field around a conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

> What will be the direction of the magnetic field be around a wire that carries current (straight conductor) between the poles of a permanent magnet?

[image]

I'm thinking it will be counterclockwise, since the X means into the page. We're using Fleming's left-hand rule in my course. Thank you!

Comment: *I'm thinking it will be counterclockwise, since the X means into the page* ...are we to ignore the field of the poles?

Comment: I think that the field of the poles is not the be ignored in this question. And that's what I've been thinking about. We are given 4 options for this: A. in to the page B. out of the page C. clockwise D. counterclockwise.

Comment: Why is the X needed - does the conductor carry current?

Comment: Yep, it does carry current. The x means that it is going "in".

Comment: Mention that please. And you do mean magnetic field not force on the wire?

Comment: Indeed, direction of magnetic field (:

Comment: direction of field around wire is clockwise by right hand rule.